# Why does converting data into a Time Series change the values and how do you change them back?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, forecasting

I imported data and converted into a simple time series.

```
  claims <- read.csv("C:/claimsrawdatabyweek.csv")

   # time series with 52 data points per year 
   em<-ts(claims[,4],start=c(2009,44),frequency=52)
```

It changed the values from

```
3496
2453
2311
2559
3149
5103
4951
4165
4340
4868
3862
2811
3583
3469
3171
2660
2772
2223
2115
```

to

```
138
105
97
109
130
155
154
146
148
153
142
119
139
137
132
112
116
93
82
```

How do I calculate what these new values indicate?
I am using the tbats forecast function   `fitem<-tbats(em)`  and it is giving me forecast values that are base on these numbers. Even when I don't convert the data and use tbats, it automatically converts to these numbers.

Stated simply, I must convert the new ts values into the actuals. Why does 3496 equal 138?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a small, reproducible example with a subset of data? What does the original csv file contain? Note that if your data actually contain commas within the numbers, that might be a problem for a *comma separated value* format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the the data had imported the variables from Excel as factors `str(claims)`. When the time series function read the variables as functions, it assigned a unique digit to each value, one which was virtually untranslatable to the original. I fixed the problem by changing the class of the variables to a integer.

Comment: Argh, no. The REASON that R has imported your numbers as factors is because of the embedded comma. Changing them to integers just means you're swapping one meaningless result for another. What you SHOULD do is go back to your Excel sheet, remove the formatting, re-export and re-import your data.

Comment: Hong Ooi, good reason. I changed the question to better reflect the actual data I put into R (removed the comma).